# i have problem with inserting values in mysql using java

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I have a form that user chooses an answer from it and then i take the value of the chosen answer and insert 3 values in the data base but there are two problems 1) i insert 3 rows but i find only one in mysql 2)the chosen_answer value is always null in mysql, when i put a number instead of chosen_answer it works !

```
<form  action ="Thanks.jsp" method ="get">


    <p><input type="radio" name="ans" value= <%=answers_id[0]%>/><%=answers[0]%></p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="ans" value=<%=answers_id[1]%>/><%=answers[1]%></p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="ans" value=<%=answers_id[2]%>/><%=answers[2]%></p>

    <p><input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>



<%

        String chosen_answer = request.getParameter("ans");

        //in this loop i'm removing the chosen_answer from the array
        for (int i = 0; i < answers_id.length; i++) {
            if (answers_id[i] == chosen_answer) {
                // shifting elements
                for (int j = i; j < answers_id.length - 1; j++) {
                    answers_id[j] = answers_id[j + 1];
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        // i will make the first aid is the answer that is chosen to know if he answer it right or wronge
        String queryString3 = "INSERT INTO stud_ans VALUES("
                + "'" + ID + "',"
                + "'" + 1 + "',"
                + "'" + 7 + "') , (" + "'" + ID + "',"
                + "'" + 1 + "',"
                + "'" + 7 + "'),(" + "'" + ID + "',"
                + "'" + 1 + "',"
                + "'" + 7 + "')";
        Stmt.executeUpdate(queryString3);
        Con.close();
        RS.close();

    } catch (Exception cnfe) {
        System.err.println("Exception: " + cnfe);
    }


%>
```

Comment: Please provide more readable code. That bad indentation makes it difficult to read.

Comment: is it clearer now ?

Comment: Yep. Now, where is ID variable declared? When does it get assigned?

Comment: Please don't write your Java code in scriptlets: Move it to a .java file.

Comment: I had to do this because I'm showing an html form  @maurice

Comment: @CR0N0S I declared it in a the same file but this part was irrelevant and has no problem so I ignored it

Comment: @MohyMohamed you don't have to; even with a form.

Comment: Side note: never EVER use string concatenation to create SQL commands from user input, not even in a school project. This makes your code vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). Use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead.